# xml parser using xstream in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xstream

I am trying to parse XML using xstream. Here is how XML file looks like:

```
<Book>
<type name="story" value="true"  />
<type name="history" value="true" />
</Book>
```

The code to parse this xml is as follows:

```
public class Parsing_Xml {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("book.xml");  // load our xml file 

    XStream xStream = new XStream();
    xStream.processAnnotations(Book.class);
    Book bookObject = (Book) xStream.fromXML(fileReader);
    System.out.println(bookObject.type);
    }

    @XStreamAlias("Book")
    class Book {
        @XStreamImplicit
        List<String> type = new ArrayList<String>();

    }
}
```

And here is output I am getting:

`[, ]`

Why this does not fills Array with all type present in XML?

Comment: The `type` is not a simple string, but a tag with 2 attributes (`name` and `value`). If you had `<Book><type>foo</type><type>bar</type></Book>` you'd see `[ "foo", "bar" ]`. Can you verify this?

Comment: Convert instances to xml in a simple test rather than try to construct the xml that can be deserialized.  You'll learn how the library works that way and what it expects for a given instance.